# Function returning linear scaling amount of duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

My code below is returning duplicate data for some reason and I can't figure out why. It runs for a 9 day period (today -8) and the data inserted for today will have 1 row each, yesterday 2 of the same values, 2 days ago 3 rows of duplicate data, 3 days ago 4 and so on until the 8th day which is the limit that has 9 duplicate rows

Why is this and how do I fix it?

```
declare @CurDate datetime

-- Redo the last 7 days of transactions
select @CurDate = cast(cast(dateadd(dd,-8,getdate()) as char(11)) as datetime)

  TRUNCATE TABLE    dbo.finaltable

WHILE @Curdate <= getdate()
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp table
(
    [StatsType] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [EquipmentNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EquipmentType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Terminal] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Param] [char](200) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Error] [bit] NULL,
    [DayKey] [char](8) NULL,
    [TimeKey] [char](4) NULL,
    [DateTimeKey] bigint
)

    INSERT @temp EXEC SQLPRDC.serv.dbo.prproc @CurDate

    INSERT dbo.finaltable
(
    [StatsType]
    ,[EquipmentNo]
    ,[EquipmentType]
    ,[Terminal]
    ,[Param]
    ,[Date]
    ,[Error]
    ,[DayKey]
    ,[TimeKey]
    ,[DateTimeKey]
)
SELECT
        [StatsType]
    ,[EquipmentNo]
    ,[EquipmentType]
    ,[Terminal]
    ,[Param]
    ,[Date]
    ,[Error]
    ,[DayKey]
    ,[TimeKey]
    ,[DateTimeKey]
FROM @temp
WHERE EquipmentType = 'M'

    SELECT @CurDate = dateadd(dd,1,@CurDate)
END
```

Here is the working adjacent procedure that doesn't need a temp insert to allow for filtering

```
declare @CurDate datetime 
-- Redo the last 7 days of transactions 
select @CurDate = cast(cast(dateadd(dd,-8,getdate()) as char(11)) as datetime) 

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.finaltable 

WHILE @Curdate <= getdate() 
BEGIN 
INSERT dbo.finaltable EXEC SQLPRDC.Rtostats.dbo.prproca @CurDate 

SELECT @CurDate = dateadd(dd,1,@CurDate) 

END
```

Comment: We need DDL and DML for the tables involved with some example data to assist with this.

Comment: Declaring a variable in a loop, scalar or table, doesn't "recreate" or "initialize" it; with a scalar variable you can supply a default value but you can't with a table variable - having the declare in the loop makes no difference, the better choice is a temp table and truncate it in the loop;

Answer (score 1):

You might want to delete your @temp table in every loop, also move it out of the loop because i think it doesn't get redeclared due to ... reasons

```sql
DECLARE @temp table
(
    [StatsType] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [EquipmentNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EquipmentType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Terminal] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Param] [char](200) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Error] [bit] NULL,
    [DayKey] [char](8) NULL,
    [TimeKey] [char](4) NULL,
    [DateTimeKey] bigint
)

WHILE @Curdate <= getdate()
BEGIN
    DELETE @temp

    INSERT @temp EXEC SQLPRDC.serv.dbo.prproc @CurDate

    INSERT dbo.finaltable
(
    [StatsType]
    ,[EquipmentNo]
    ,[EquipmentType]
    ,[Terminal]
    ,[Param]
    ,[Date]
    ,[Error]
    ,[DayKey]
    ,[TimeKey]
    ,[DateTimeKey]
)
SELECT
        [StatsType]
    ,[EquipmentNo]
    ,[EquipmentType]
    ,[Terminal]
    ,[Param]
    ,[Date]
    ,[Error]
    ,[DayKey]
    ,[TimeKey]
    ,[DateTimeKey]
FROM @temp
WHERE EquipmentType = 'M'

    SELECT @CurDate = dateadd(dd,1,@CurDate)
END
```

Comment: I don't think the position of `DECLARE` makes any difference. A temp table might be wiser, then you can `TRUNCATE` it

Comment: This worked - is odd I had an adjacent proc that did the same from a different proc that didnt encounter the duplicate error
```
declare @CurDate datetime

-- Redo the last 7 days of transactions
select @CurDate = cast(cast(dateadd(dd,-8,getdate()) as char(11)) as datetime)

  TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.finaltable

WHILE @Curdate <= getdate()
BEGIN
 
 INSERT dbo.finaltable EXEC SQLPRDC.Rtostats.dbo.prproca @CurDate

 SELECT @CurDate = dateadd(dd,1,@CurDate)
END
```

Comment: Was this because i wasnt using the variable table

Comment: well, you truncated the table there? that's same as delete

Comment: the new code you posted doesn't make sense cause you first add data then truncate it? it will lead to just a single row.

Comment: the truncate is before the add data and begin, let me make it look better to be clearer

Comment: just add a select * from yourtable somewhere in the loop in the old and new code, and you should be able to understand what's going on :)